# LAPS Find-AdmPwdExtendedRights : Object not found

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am setting up LAPS at the moment and want to use the standard "Computers" Organisational Unit.

I am working through the setup guide but I keep getting this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN> Find-AdmPwdExtendedRights -OrgUnit "Comp
uters" | Format-Table
Find-AdmPwdExtendedRights : Object not found
At line:1 char:1
+ Find-AdmPwdExtendedRights -OrgUnit "Computers" | Format-Table
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Find-AdmPwdExtendedRights], N
   otFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AdmPwd.PSTypes.NotFoundException,AdmPwd.PS.FindE
   xtendedRights
```

I get similar error message about `Object not found` when I try using the `Set-AdmPwdComputerSelfPermission` commandlet etc.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and found two different reasons:

1. You have not extended your AD schema yet - this will result in the `Find-AdmPwdExtendedRights` cmdlet always returning " : No such object found". You can work around this by using the `-SchemaNotUpdated` parameter in the newer (6.0+) version of LAPS.
2. The builtin Computers container in Active Directory is not an OU in the traditional sense and does not have the same ACLs. Try it on a different OU

Answer (score 1):

"Computers" is not an Organizational Unit, it's a container. The script requires an Organizational Unit.